# Can someone explain this inequality to me?

Tags: calculus

[image]

How did they justify

$$\left | \int_{a}^{b} x(t) dt \right| \leq (b - a)\max_{t \in J} x(t)$$

Comment: They don't. Note that you have written $x(t)$ where the text has $|x(t)|$.

Comment: Set $g(t)=\max x(t) \ \forall a<t<b$, so you get a rectangle $(b-a)g(t)$

Comment: Intuitively, $$\left|\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b x(t)dt\right|\le\max_{t\in[a,b]}|x(t)|$$ says that the magnitude of an average is less than the maximum magnitude attained.

Comment: That's what i thought too, it resembled the average value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take *any* Riemann sum wrt *any* partition $\,\{a=t_0<t_1<\ldots <t_n=b\}\,$ of $\,[a,b]\,$ , and for any points $\,c_k\in [t_k-t_{k-1}]\,$:

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^nx(c_k)(t_k-t_{k-1})\right|\le ||x||\sum_{k=1}^n(t_k-t_{k-1})=||x|| (b-a)$$

Answer (score 1):

Take the case where $x(t)\ge0$ for all $t$. Draw the graph of $x(t)$, and draw a box around it of length $b-a$ and height $\max x(t)$, and see the inequality geometrically. Then work out how to make this go through even if $x(t)$ is not non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

1) $|\int f|\leq \int |f|$.

2) $|x(t)|\leq \max_J |x|$ for all $t\in J$.

3) $f\leq g$ implies $\int_a^bf\leq \int_a^bg$.